# JPA Hibernate com Postgres - 2 transações

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, transações, padrão-dao

Comecei a usar o hibernate há 1 mês.Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples de banco para faculdade.
Tenho uma classe conta, que possui o método SacarValor :

```
public boolean SacarValor(long numConta, double valor) {
    EntityManager em = FabricaEM.getEntityManager();
    Conta c = null;

    try {
        c = em.find(Conta.class, numConta);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        if ((c.getSaldo() - valor) < 0) {//testar
            return false;
        } else {
            c.setSaldo(c.getSaldo() - valor);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.getTransaction().begin();//nova transacao para registrar o movimento
            MovimentoDAO mdao = new MovimentoDAO();
            Movimento m = new Movimento();
            m.setTipoMovimento(TipoMovimento.SAQUE);
            m.setDataMovimento(Calendar.getInstance());
            m.setHoraMovimento(Time.valueOf(LocalTime.now()));
            m.setValorMovimento(5);
            m.setConta(em.find(Conta.class, numConta));
            mdao.save(m, numConta);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        return true;//removido
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Estou gostaria que quando o método(SacarValor) fosse executado, um movimento fosse registrado logo em seguida, porém estou recebendo o seguinte retorno.

> ```
>  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
>
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
>
>   at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:132)
>
>   at modelo.dao.ContaDAO.SacarValor(ContaDAO.java:153)
>
>   at modelo.tests.ContaTeste.main(ContaTeste.java:94)
>
>   Java Result: 1
> ```

Como eu posso realizar duas transações em seguida, usando a mesma transação?

OBS : **A subtração, na tabela Conta é feita no BD, mas não é registrado um novo movimento.**

Answer (score 1):

**Problema resolvido!**

Resolução : 
1ª parte : (Annotation no ArrayList movimentos)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "conta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

private List<Movimento> movimentos = new ArrayList<>();
```

2 ª parte : (Método para adicionar os movimentos)

```
public void adicionarMovimento(Movimento m){
    m.setConta(this);
    this.movimentos.add(m);
}
```

3ª parte : (No método SacarValor, quando for persistir)
Além de setar o saldo, chamei o método adicionarMovimento(m);

```
c.setSaldo(c.getSaldo() - valor);
            c.adicionarMovimento(m);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Mais detalhes : [Peguei informações aqui](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que tu nao precise dessa linha:

```
 em.getTransaction().begin();//nova transacao para registrar o movimento,
```

Sua transação ja ta aberta antes de entrar no try, e quando entra nele, ainda está aberta...

Depois tu tenta iniciar novamente uma nova transação.

Comment: obrigado, mas eu tentei sem essa linha... retorna o seguinte : 
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active**